# Regressão linear ponderada utilizando o inverso da variância como fator de ponderação

Tags: r, regressão

Tenho o seguinte conjunto de dados que estabelece uma relação entre duas variáveis “X” e “Y”:

```
df <- data.frame(X=c(25,25,25,25,25,25,50,50,50,50,50,50,
75,75,75,75,75,75,100,100,100,100,100,100,
125,125,125,125,125,125,150,150,150,150,150,150),    
Y=c(2457524,2391693,2450828,2391252,2444638,2360293,
4693194,4844527,4835596,4878092,4809226,4722253,
7142763,7182769,7135550,7173920,7216871,7076359,
9496553,9537788,9405825,9439201,9609870,9707734,
12031958,12027037,11935594,11930086,12154132,
12096462,14298064,14396607,13964716,14221039,
14283992,14042220))
```

Considere o seguinte problema:

“Ajustar um modelo linear ponderado usando a função “lm” e, como fator de   ponderação, o inverso da variância de “Y” para cada nível de “X””. Ou seja, o modelo linear deverá ser ponderado pelo inverso da variância de cada nível de “X”. Neste caso, como podemos especificar a relação funcional ponderada? Existe alguma função específica para ser entrada como argumento em “*weights*”?

Detalhe técnico: Só vale ajustar pela função “lm”. Não vale ajustar por nenhum outro método (gls, glm, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Basta criar o vetor de pesos desejado para resolver este problema. No teu caso, chamei este vetor de `pesos`:

```
variancias_condicionais <- aggregate(df$Y, list(df$X), var)$x
quantidade_X <- as.numeric(table(df$X))
pesos <- rep(1/variancias_condicionais, quantidade_X)

ajuste <- lm(Y ~ X, data=df, weights=pesos)
summary(ajuste)

Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ X, data = df, weights = pesos)

Weighted Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.17331 -0.71861 -0.08895  0.84733  2.42540 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    28185      22538   1.251     0.22    
X              95300        330 288.777   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.097 on 34 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9996,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9996 
F-statistic: 8.339e+04 on 1 and 34 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: Olá Marcus. Estamos quase lá... Mandei imprimir a variância de cada nível de "X" e não pude deixar de notar que ela ficou igual para todos os níveis da variável  "X" (25,50, 75, 100, 125, 150). Precisamos corrigir isto pois o correto seria calcular o inverso da variância cada nível de X.

Comment: O resultado esperado para o vetor de pesos seria: 6.20046E-10
6.20046E-10, 6.20046E-10, 6.20046E-10, 6.20046E-10, 6.20046E-10, 1.86313E-10, 1.86313E-10, 1.86313E-10, 1.86313E-10, 1.86313E-10, 1.86313E-10, 4.28484E-10, 4.28484E-10, 4.28484E-10, 4.28484E-10
4.28484E-10, 4.28484E-10, 7.96637E-11, 7.96637E-11, 7.96637E-11
7.96637E-11, 7.96637E-11, 7.96637E-11, 1.29098E-10, 1.29098E-10
1.29098E-10, 1.29098E-10, 1.29098E-10, 1.29098E-10, 3.67609E-11
3.67609E-11, 3.67609E-11, 3.67609E-11, 3.67609E-11, 3.67609E-11 e Parabéns pela visão elegante !!!

Comment: Não entendi de onde vieram estes valores. Por favor, me explique como a variância de uma constante é um número diferente de zero.

Comment: Código editado.

Comment: Considere este que esta melhor explicado: Para X=25 (primeiro nível de X), temos os seguintes valores de "Y": 2457524, 2391693, 2450828, 2391252, 2444638, 2360293 logo a variância de Y dado X é igual a var(Y/X)=1612784428. O inverso desta variância é igual 1/var(Y/X)=6.20046E-10. Veja que este valor foi repetido para cada uma da repetições do nível 25 em X. Esta deve ser a lógica para os demais níveis de X, ou seja, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150. Por favor note, que para cada nível de X haverá uma variância diferente.

Comment: Outra coisa: considere níveis genéricos (N1,N2, N3, ...) pois não queremos restringir o código ao exemplo.

Comment: Muito bom Marcus!!! Como sempre uma reposta muito elegante!

Comment: Obrigado. Se possível, além de votar na resposta, aceite-a. Assim, outras pessoas no futuro saberão mais facilmente que esta resposta resolve o teu problema.

Comment: Marcus, como é o procedimento para aceitar a resposta? Eu sou novo por aqui e ainda estou na fase de aprendizagem do site (risos).

Comment: [Aqui tem um tutorial explicando passo a passo, com imagens](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/49033).